# How to reference BezierPath in a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to detect Taps inside BezierPaths in a UIView and have found many references to the containsPoint method. However I cannot seem to find how to actually reference the BezierPaths from my ViewController.

I have set up:

```
class func drawSA(frame targetFrame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 69, height: 107), resizing: ResizingBehavior = .aspectFit, SACountries: [String: ViewController.CountryStruct])
{

    let myPath = UIBezierPath()
    myPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 32.24, y: 8.61))
    myPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 31.99, y: 8.29))
    myPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 31.78, y: 8.19))
    myPath.close()
}
```

The Beziers are drawn in this function, called by:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
```

In the main ViewController, I have the following function for detecting a Tap on the UIView:

```
@objc func SATap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    let location = sender.location(in: self.SAView)

    // how do I call containsPoint from here?
}
```

How do I call containsPoint from here?

The bezierPaths are drawn correctly at runtime.

Comment: Save the path as a property of your view. and do call containsPath with `self.SAView.myPath`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Paths are created in a Class Function within a separate Class, I cannot save them to the View directly.

I solved this by putting the UIBezierPaths into a Dictionary and then return the Dictionary. An Array would work too, but this way I can access specific Paths easily.

```
class func drawSA(frame targetFrame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 71, height: 120), resizing: ResizingBehavior = .aspectFit, SACountries: [String: ViewController.CountryStruct]) -> ([String: UIBezierPath])
{
    var Paths = [String: UIBezierPath]()

    let myPath = UIBezierPath()
    myPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 32.24, y: 8.61))
    myPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 31.99, y: 8.29))
    myPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 31.78, y: 8.19))
    myPath.close()

    Paths["mP"] = myPath


    let myPath2 = UIBezierPath()
    myPath2.move(to: CGPoint(x: 32.24, y: 8.61))
    myPath2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 31.99, y: 8.29))
    myPath2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 31.78, y: 8.19))
    myPath2.close()

    Paths["mP2"] = myPath2


    return Paths
}
```

I then used `View.addLayer` to create Layers in the View and added the `Layer.name` property to each Layer when creating them with a For In Loop on the Dictionary:

```
for path in Paths.keys.sorted()
    {
        self.layer.addSublayer(CreateLayer(path)) // The Function simply creates a CAShapeLayer
    }
```

I then used the Dictionary in the Gesture Function:

```
@objc func ATap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    let location = sender.location(in: self.SAView)
    // You need to Scale Location if your CAShapeLayers are Scaled

    for path in SAView.Paths
    {
        let value = path.value

        value.contains(location)

        if value.contains(location)
        {
            for (index, layer) in SAView.layer.sublayers!.enumerated()
            {
               if layer.name == path.key
                {
                    // Do something when specific layer is Tapped
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There may well be better ways of doing this, but it's all working and performs well.